# Convert string into hex to send for serial communication

Tags: python, string, hex

I have a string with numbers `5:240`. From that I have to send the numbers from string by their hex representation. The number must be with in range of two bytes. But, I want to send the exact representation on my serial port like `'\x00\x05\x00\xf0'`. Can anybody help me out on this?

I have tried following snippets but no success:

```
b='5:240'
b = b.split(':')
for i in range(len(b)):
    print hex(int(b[i]))
    print len(hex(int(b[i])))
```

Result:

```
0x5
3
0xf0
4
```

Output shows the hex conversion but it would not be possible for me to send it on serial port, cause the length is varying. Can anybody resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: With reference from Selcuk's answer. I got the following solution.

```
def word_hex(w):
    a = int(w / 256)
    b = w % 256
    return "{0:#0{1}x}{2:#0{3}x}".format(a,4,b,4).replace("0x", "")

b='5:240'
b = b.split(':')
for i in b:
    print(word_hex(int(i)).decode("hex"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [hexadecimal format specifier, `x`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
def word_hex(w):
    a = int(w / 256)
    b = w % 256
    return "{0:#0{1}x}{2:#0{3}x}".format(a,4,b,4).replace("0x", "\\x")

b='5:240'
b = b.split(':')
for i in b:
    print(word_hex(int(i)))
```

prints

```
\x00\x05
\x00\xf0
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But it is just converting to number to hexadecimal, where I have to send it also on the serial port. For your solution it gives me `len(word_hex(int(i))) = 8` which are sending 8 chars on the port. I need only 2 Bytes (chars) for particular number.

Comment: OK. I got it after some tweaking in script. To get desired output, just have remove `"\\x"` by keeping it blank also have to edit line. `print (word_hex(int(i))).encode("hex")`.